# Excel, VBA, UserForm: Populate combobox based on selection in another combobox

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have created a userform with some comboboxes, based on combobox2 I would like to populate combobox1.

In combobox2 there are 6 items to choose from 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 25+

Based on the selected item in Combobox1 I would like to populate combobox2 as following:

If ItemA is selected, Combobox1 should be populated from range in Sheet ”supply_to_production” range (T6:T1000)

If ItemB is selected, Combobox1 should be populated from range in Sheet ”supply_to_production” range (V6:V1000)

If ItemC is selected, Combobox1 should be populated from range in Sheet ”supply_to_production” range (X6:X1000)

If ItemD is selected, Combobox1 should be populated from range in Sheet ”supply_to_production” range (Z6:Z1000)

If ItemE is selected, Combobox1 should be populated from range in Sheet ”supply_to_production” range (AB6:AB1000)

If ItemF is selected, Combobox1 should be populated from range in Sheet ”supply_to_production” range (AD
6:AD1000)

I have tried the code bellow, it is not giving me any error but is also does not give me any list in combobox1.

`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ComboBox2
    .AddItem "17"
    .AddItem "19"
    .AddItem "21"
    .AddItem "23"
    .AddItem "25"
    .AddItem "25+"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Update()
Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox2.ListIndex

ComboBox1.Clear

Select Case index

 Case "17":
  ComboBox1.List = [SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION!T6:T1000]
 Case "19":
  ComboBox1.List = [SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION!V6:V1000]
 Case "21":
  ComboBox1.List = [SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION!X6:X1000]
 Case "23":
  ComboBox1.List = [SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION!Z6:Z1000]
 Case "25":
  ComboBox1.List = [SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION!AB6:AB1000]
 Case "25+":
  ComboBox1.List = [SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION!AD6:AD1000] 

End Select

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Me.ComboBox2.List = Array(17, 19, 21, 23, 25, "25+")
    
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    
    'Don't have magic numbers, have an easy way to change hard-coded values
    Const lStartRow As Long = 6
    
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    Dim sColumn As String
    Select Case CStr(Me.ComboBox2.Value)
        Case "17":  sColumn = "T"
        Case "19":  sColumn = "V"
        Case "21":  sColumn = "X"
        Case "23":  sColumn = "Z"
        Case "25":  sColumn = "AB"
        Case "25+": sColumn = "AD"
    End Select
    
    If Len(sColumn) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'No valid option selected from ComboBox2
    
    'Dynamically size the data
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION")
    Dim rData As Range:  Set rData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, sColumn), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sColumn).End(xlUp))
    
    Me.ComboBox1.List = rData.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, this works perfectly, even better than I asked for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're compiling, where `Option Explicit` may have saved you?

Try referencing the full range and using the `ComboBox2.Value` for your `Select`, such that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim columnReference as String
    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "17":
            columnReference = "T"
        Case "19":
            columnReference = "V"
        Case "21":
            columnReference = "X"
        Case "23":
            columnReference = "Z"
        Case "25":
            columnReference = "AB"
        Case "25+":
            columnReference = "AD"
    End Select
    With Sheets("SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION")
        ComboBox2.List = .Range(.Cells(6,columnReference),.Cells(1000,columnReference)).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit1:  Added name of subroutine... `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`, which should trigger the event.  Plus, showing images of a quick example which follows this model:

[image]
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("animal", "food")
End Sub


Private Sub combobox1_change()
    Dim columnReference As Long
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "animal"
            columnReference = 1
        Case "food"
            columnReference = 2
    End Select
    With Sheets(1)
        ComboBox2.List = .Range(.Cells(2, columnReference), .Cells(4, columnReference)).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Cyril, thanks your code looks neater but unfortunately it does also not give me any list in combox1.

Comment: @user20378135 just realized your subroutine title... `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` should trigger this, not `_Update`

Comment: I have changed it into 'Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()' but somehow still not working.

Comment: @user20378135 look at my updated example which does exactly what is expected/intended.  I think the only change is the difference between `columnReference` via `long` or `string`... both work (tested each)

Comment: if i rebuild your example, your example code works, somehow i cannot get it working in my own file... I'll try to figure out why...

Comment: @user20378135 without seeing your updated code, I can only guess... as you stated that this example code worked, verify the names of your specific comboboxes, how they tie into the userform, etc.

Answer (score 2):

### Populate Combo Box Based On Selection in Another Combo Box

**UserForm e.g. `UserForm1` ([careful](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/))**

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox2.List = Array("17", "19", "21", "23", "25", "25+")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SUPPLY_TO_PRODUCTION")
    Dim arg As Range: Set arg = ws.Range("T6:T1000," _
        & "V6:V1000,X6:X1000,Z6:Z1000,AB6:AB1000,AD6:AD1000")
        
    Dim aIndex As Long: aIndex = ComboBox2.ListIndex + 1 ' zero-based
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = GetColumnRange(arg.Areas(aIndex))
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = DictColumn(Data)
    If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ComboBox1.List = dict.Keys
    
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Function GetColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber > rg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
        If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetColumnRange = Data
        Else
            GetColumnRange = .Value
        End If
    End With

End Function

Function DictColumn( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Variant) _
As Object
    Const ProcName As String = "DictColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    If IsMissing(ColumnIndex) Then
       c = LBound(Data, 2) ' use first column Index2
    Else
       c = CLng(ColumnIndex)
    End If
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, c)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(CStr(Key)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
   
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and blanks
    
    Set DictColumn = dict

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```